# Linking.addEventListener('url') handler in a non-root component is not being called

Tags: react-native

I have a react-native app which is using `Linking.addEventListener()` for the `'URL'` type in two places. One is the root component, `src/App/index.js`, the other is a child component. The handler in the root component is being called. The handler in the child component is not being called. I've done the research online and I know about the native code snippet(s) that need to be placed for `Linking` functionality to work, that's not the issue as the root component's handler is being called just fine. I cannot fathom why the child node's `Linking.addEventListener` is not working. Any ideas? Thanks.

Child component's code with one regex omitted:

```js
    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.getAssessment()
        Linking.addEventListener('url', ({ url }) => {
            url = url.replace(<omitted_regex>);
            const [action, value] = url.split(/\//)
            switch (action) {
                case 'assessment':
                    if (value === 'prev') {
                        this.goPrev()
                    }
                    if (value === 'finishLater') {
                        this.finishLater()
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    console.debug(action, value)
            }
        });
    }
```